# Using XML to program game levels in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, xml, cocoa, macos

Im making a fairly big game for Mac appstore, and i would like to control my levels using XML. Basically I just need to be able to read co-ordinates out of the XML document and into cocoa, where I can use them to move objects for each level. How do i parse this file in cocoa?

Thanks for your help

Comment: What precisely is your question?

Comment: how do i parse the file in cocoa?

Comment: Possible duplicates: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237757/cocoa-objective-c-best-practice-to-parse-xml-document) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072979/how-do-i-read-and-write-xml-in-cocoa-touch) [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706698/objective-c-desktop-xml-file-web-page-to-nstableview) [4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964503/nsxmlparser-on-the-iphone-how-do-i-use-it-given-a-xml-file-newb-here) [5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089737/parsing-xml-in-cocoa) [6](http://goo.gl/43aDe) [...](http://goo.gl/09gm8)

Comment: Please search for existing questions before posting. There are already a zillion related questions here on Stack Overflow, and I'm sure that at least one of them will help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[NSXML](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSXML_Concepts/NSXML.html) should have everything you need to get started.