# XML Parsing in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parsing XML in Cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089737/parsing-xml-in-cocoa)

Hello friends,

I want to use xml parsing. Any Link or tutorial for xml parsing.which xml parsing are efficient for parsing.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509560/using-xml-to-program-game-levels-in-cocoa) [2](http://goo.gl/raDFs) [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072979/how-do-i-read-and-write-xml-in-cocoa-touch) [4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706698/objective-c-desktop-xml-file-web-page-to-nstableview) [5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964503/nsxmlparser-on-the-iphone-how-do-i-use-it-given-a-xml-file-newb-here) [6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089737/parsing-xml-in-cocoa) [...](http://goo.gl/09gm8)

Comment: There were _many_ choices to consider when selecting the appropriate duplicate. I think [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089737) best answers your question.

Answer (score 3):

**How To Choose The Best XML Parser for Your iPhone Project:**

http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project

**Make NSXMLParser your friend:**

http://codesofa.com/blog/archive/2008/07/23/make-nsxmlparser-your-friend.html

And of course, **NSXMLParser class documentation:**

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

If you only have some simple and small xml files have a look here

http://www.memention.com/blog/2009/10/31/The-XML-Runner.html